# Looking for a source for Valence/Arousal values Russell's advance circumplex model of emotion?

Tags: emotion, experimental-psychology

I've been looking for a chart/table of Valence and Arousal values from the advanced Russell's model such as the one referenced in this article https://www.researchgate.net/publication/50805681_Asymmetrical_Facial_Expressions_based_on_an_Advanced_Interpretation_of_Two-dimensional_Russells_Emotional_Model

I'm unable to find anything that isn't a picture, and what I'm really looking for is a table/spreadsheet with the emotions and the valence/arousal values for each emotion.

Is there a source for this that I can reference?

Answer (score 1):

Circumplex models of emotion with the dimensions 'arousal' and 'valence' are not grounded with neurobiological support.

There is however an alternative 'atlas' model with two dimensions that does have neurobiological support (Mobbs, 2020).  The atlas model uses the dimensions of 'affiliation' and 'dominance' with broad emotional categories as shown below.  The atlas is supported with a catalogue of over 3000 emotions each with precise coordinates.

[image]

The facial expressions for each location in the atlas is shown below:

[image: https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0227877.g005]

Mobbs AED (2020) An atlas of personality, emotion and behaviour. PLOS ONE 15(1): e0227877. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0227877

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but it does offer ideas. We're using Russell's model for the basis of determining external facial expressions.

Comment: I'm unaware of a table with emotions with coordinates for valence and arousal values.  Please do share if you find it as would be very interested.

Comment: I ended up typing the numbers in by hand based on a HQ version of the model.  Then plotted them on a graph and overlayed my results on the model to verify I got everything.  Took about an hour with Excel.